# SunFire LOM - MIBS?

Tags: snmp, sun

I've got a collection of SunFire hardware here, X2100, X2200 and X4250.  Sun seem to have made it spectacularly difficult to find MIBs that I can use with net-snmp to monitor the state of the hardware using the LOM hardware.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I need MIBs for

```
  SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0 = OID: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.42.2.208.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MIBs you need are in Sun's "Tools and Drivers" ISO for each server:

- http://www.sun.com/servers/x64/x2100/downloads.jsp
- http://www.sun.com/servers/x64/x2200/downloads.jsp
- http://www.sun.com/servers/x64/x4250/downloads.jsp

Comment: So they are - though not mentioned in the overview of those ISOs on the download site, which is why I overlooked them.  Thanks :)